# How do I fix this "Client Privacy Violation" error?

Tags: angular.json

```
import { AppErrorHandler } from './../common/app-error-handler';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { kMaxLength } from 'buffer';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IlceService extends DataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private router: Router) { super(http,"/app/ilce",router) }
  
  getIlcesByIlId(pIl:string):Observable<any>{ 
    var headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
    });


   
    return this.http.get(this.backEndAddress.concat('/by/il/',pIl),{headers}) 
    .pipe(
      catchError(err=>throwError(AppErrorHandler.createAppError(err,this.router)))
    );
  }


}
```

ilce.service.ts sends user information outside the application. This may constitute a Privacy Violation

return this.http.get(this.backEndAddress.concat('/by/il/',pIl),{headers} is this here give me  client privacy violation error there are many different kind of methot but not find correct method. how to correct this code write?unexpected violation error ;

please help  thank you very much.